# Database Project References and Deployment issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have a database project, Db1, that references a server project DbSrv1. Db1 includes some synonyms for some tables in another database Db2, consequently I also reference a Db2  database project. Now Db2 in turn, references its own DbSrv2.

To sum up these are all the database references for Db1:
    
- DbSrv1
    
- ...DBSchemas\master.dbschema
    
- ...DBSchemas\msdb.dbschema
    
- Db2
    
- DbSrv2

The project will build okay now, but I can't deploy it because there are 2 server projects referenced (TSD01234 The source model contains 2 server option elements.). I am not sure how can I get out of this. I can't remove either server projects as I will get all the unresolved references.

On another hand is it posible to work without referincing all these database and resolve the unresolved references some other way (like using variables)? I am a newbie in this area so I need as more info as it helps but not more.

Thanks in advance

Iulian